# Area of a surface of revolution $x=e^{2y}$ between $y=0$ and $y=\frac12$

Tags: calculus, integration, area, solid-of-revolution

I have the following function: $x=e^{2y}$ between $y=0$ and $y=\frac12$.

I try to calculate the surface area of revolution after turning the function around the $y$-axis.

The integral that I have left is:
$$\int_0^{\frac12}2\pi e^{2y}\sqrt{1+4e^{4y}}\,dy$$

Comment: Try substituting $z=e^{2y}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The integral can be written as$$\int_0^\frac12 2\pi e^{2y}\sqrt{1+4e^{4y}}\,dy=\int_1^e \pi \sqrt{1+4u^2}\,du$$
using the substitution $u=e^{2y}$.

Comment: thanks for answering, why does the definite integral of values change?

Comment: @Python241820 Do you mean the limits? Because you change the variables, this means the limits change. The lower $u$ limit is $e^{2\cdot 0}=1$, the upper $u$ limit is $e^{2\cdot\frac12}=e$.

Comment: @JohnDoe its true, THANKSSS

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use substitution $2e^{2y}=u$ to find $\displaystyle\pi\int_{2}^{2e}\sqrt{1+u^2}du$ and now let $u=\sinh u$.